# Extracting .dict.dz files on Mac OSX

Tags: mac, macos, dictionary, compression

I've tried to install `dtrx` on the terminal on Mac OSX and after downloading and extracting the the tarball from http://download.huzheng.org/ja/stardict-ej-edict-2.4.2.tar.bz2, it contains a [`.dict.dz` file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DICT):

Using dtrx again:

```
dtrx je-edict-kanji.dict.dz
```

It produced the `je-edict-kanji.dict.dz.1` file that contains the desired dictionary file but the lines are all squashed into one without the proper newline:

```
$ cat je-edict-kanji.dict.dz.1

暴く to disclose, to divulge, to expose暴れる to act violently, to rage, to struggle, to be riotous阿鼻叫喚 agonizing cries, a pandemonium, two of Buddhism's hells浴びる to bathe, to bask in the sun, to shower浴びせる to pour on危ない dangerous, critical, grave, uncertain, unreliable, limping, narrow, close, watch out!...
```

If the extraction was done on a Windows machine, this shouldn't happen. And it would produce:

```
暴く to disclose, to divulge, to expose
暴れる to act violently, to rage, to struggle, to be riotous
阿鼻叫喚 agonizing cries, a pandemonium, two of Buddhism's hells
浴びる to bathe, to bask in the sun, to shower
浴びせる to pour on
危ない dangerous, critical, grave, uncertain, unreliable, limping, narrow, close, watch out!
```

**How to extracting .dict.dz files on Mac OSX?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about installable software. Try [su] or [apple.se[.

Comment: [apple.se[ -->  [apple.se]